# Mismatch between Spring Actuator's "jvm.memory.max" metric and Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()

Tags: spring-boot, jvm, heap-memory, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer

I'm trying out Spring Boot Actuator and looking at the "/actuator/metrics/jvm.memory.max" endpoint.

I am also running my Springboot app with the following JVM option:

-Xmx104m

I created an endpoint ("/memory" which returns the Total, Free, Used & Max memory for the app. I used Runtime.getRuntime().getXXX() methods for this.

The question that I have is that the value Springboot's "jvm.memory.max" shows me in bytes does not match with the -Xmx value and what the "/memory" endpoint shows me.

Any thoughts why this mismatch?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Spring Boot uses Micrometer for its metrics support. The `jvm.memory.max` metrics is produced by Mirometer's [JvmMemoryMetrics class](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/7a26d4740a0c2b31d36b847d3c93f13267957d3a/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/binder/jvm/JvmMemoryMetrics.java#L93-L97) using `MemoryPoolMXBean.getUsage().getMax()`.

The `MemoyPoolMXBean` exposes information about both heap and non-heap memory and Micrometer separates these using tags on the `jvm.memory.max` metric. In the output shown in the question, the value is the heap and non-heap memory combined which is why it is not the same as the heap-specific value configured with `-Xmx`.

You can drill down into a metric using its tags and query parameters. This is described in the Actuator's [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.2.RELEASE/actuator-api/html/#metrics-retrieving-metric). For example, to get the max heap memory, you would use http://localhost:9001/actuator/metrics/jvm.memory.max?tag=area:heap.

Comment: Thanks Andy! That explains it and thanks for sharing the relevant documentation link as well.